# @include establish-baseline($base-font-size); generates no output?

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I have the following in my scss file:

```
@import compass
$base-font-size: 16px;
$base-line-height: 20px;
$lato: 'Lato, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif';


html {
  @include establish-baseline($base-font-size);
  font-family: $lato;
}
```

but when I check my CSS, the @include establish-baseline rule doesn't output anything and I get no compilation errors. Anyone any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The main problem:**

In your case, you should put the imported file name `"compass"` between quotes:

`@import "compass"`

If you only want to import `establish-baseline mixin` use instead:

`@import "compass/typography/vertical_rhythm";`

**Some tips:**

- It's not necessary to set `$base-font-size: 16px` because imported compass files comes with a `$base-font-size: 16px !default`variable declaration
- As @nyuen says you don't need to pass `$base-font-size` as an argument and you should move the `@include establish-baseline` out of the html.

Here is the modified code:

```
// you should use the file name to import between quotes
@import "compass";
// $base-font-size: 16px !default; it's already declared in compass
// $base-font-size: 16px;
$base-line-height: 20px;
$lato: 'Lato, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif';

// This include should be use out of any selector
@include establish-baseline();

html {
  font-family: $lato;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm just learning about vertical rhythms as well, and here's my suggestion:

I think the syntax should be "@include establish-baseline;" (without the $base-font-size argument because when you include the establish-baseline mixin, it automatically looks for that argument, as well as $base-line-height), and you can also move that line out of your html selector to under the $base-line-height declaration.